# Outlook error: “A dialogue box is open. Close it and try it again.”

Tags: outlook, windows-server-2003, outlook-2007

When trying to open Outlook 2007 on Windows Server 2003, I get this error message:

> “A dialogue box is open. Close it and try it again.”

I try and open Outlook in safe mode by using `outlook /safe` (in the Run command) and it works fine after it says configuring outlook accounts "Please enter your full name and initials below" (the full name and intials fields are already prefilled) and I click the OK button on the same and I answer the RSS Feeds subscription as either Yes or No.

Once I try closing and reopening Outlook, again I see the same error message as “A dialogue box is open. Close it and try it again.”

This does not let me open any new window to send emails. How can I fix whatever is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a windows update on windows 2003 server.
I did a system restore to an earlier point and it worked fine. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be due to an add-in that is acting up.  Try to determine which add-in it is by disabling them one by one until it is identified.  To disable an add-in, go to the Tools menu, click Trust Center, and then click Add-ins. A list of add-ins are listed.  For each Type of add-in you see, choose them in the Manage listbox at the bottem and click Go.  Uncheck the add-in to disable it.

Comment: I also tried disabling the "Automatic Download" option by going to the Tools menu, clicking on Trust Center. I tried this but it still works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Task Manager to end any other Outlook processes, then try opening it again. Your problem could be due to a non-responsive Outlook process, or a background one.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work after closing it through the Task Manager and opening it again. The issue persists.

Comment: Then I would only suggest a full uninstall of Outlook and an install of the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use a virtual window manager (like virtuawin or bbbLean)? If so, you may not see the modal dialog box as it is in another virtual window and Outlook will not accept any input. It happens to me often and at first I was frustrated that Outlook 'hangs' frequently and is not a robust app. For me it was dialog box that said something like "Do you want to auto-archive the folder?".

The dialog box may also be hidden behind the main window. You can try using Alt-TAB to cycle through you windows and you should see the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hit/hold "Alt-Esc" to cycle through windows and pull up the hidden dialog box.  Alt-Tab usually won't do the same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).